# Is there a way to get to partially uploaded files?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I need to save the uploaded file even if the connection fails at some point (if it fails, then save as much as was uploaded).
Is there a way in PHP to get to that part of a file, that was uploaded before (e.g.) the connection to the server has failed? 
(when there is an UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL error in `$_FILES['file']['error']`)

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer has to do with how PHP handles cancelled uploads, mime boundaries, etc.

Comment: I'm assuming that if partial data is relevant, you're probably dealing with text uploads. Perhaps allowing the client uploading the file to split the content into parts and upload each one individually; Then if the connection drops you'll still have some of the smaller parts already uploaded. Perhaps this approach of staying away from "all or nothing" will be useful.

Comment: @Lix It's actually video files that I want to save even partially, but I think that this is the best way to go. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comments, it's is not worth wasting your time trying to do some magic with PHP.

HTML5 already supports chucked file uploads, it would be a much better approach to use some sort of JavaScript library or something else that relies on this technology. I can recommend [FlowJS](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) (the demo speaks for itself), but if you don't like it - I am pretty sure there are plenty more around the web with the same functionality.